# Retrieve "Integrated in build " link type from workitems in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We are in process of retrieving specific fields from work items in VSTS following the instructions from [Fetch work items with queries programatically in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/quickstarts/work-item-quickstart)

But unable to fetch "Integrated in build" Development link type using "Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" reference field, all other fields are retrievable.

How can we retrieve the Development links associated to a work item?

Comment: What's the process template do you use? And how did you change your code?

Comment: We use CMMI template, can we use reference field "Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" to fetch the build details added as Integerated in build link type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Development links via the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-links-and-attachments-1) to get work item relations:

```
GET https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitem ID}?$expand=relations&api-version=1.0
```

Then you can get the Development links in the ArtifactLinks through the output.

And **the `Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild` field can not be used to get the build links for VSTS**, since the `Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild` field is designed for the XAML build (not vNext build). 
And you can also find relation information in the blog [Automatic linking work items to builds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/25/automatic-linking-work-items-to-builds/):

> The build fields are populated with build numbers only for XML builds.
>   This will continue to work as is for XML builds. The new build system
>   does not populate these fields.